# Choosing a mining pool

Tags: mining-pools, litecoin

I've read that some mining pools disappears all of a sudden, and your hard earned coins also disappear if you didn't transfer them ontime.

My question is, how do you go about picking a pool which isn't going to disappear?

I've not done mining before, but want to try out litecoin mining.

Or is it better for me to start mining without using a pool if that's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are starting off, I will assume you do not have the computing power to solo-mine.

It's just easier to join a pool, and with regards to trusting one, I would stick with something that has been around for a while. For Litecoin I've used [wemineltc](http://wemineltc.com) and have no complaints.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have seen https://litecoin.info/Mining_pool_comparison, and you are really interested in finding out Litecoin's equivalent of https://blockchain.info/pools to discover the pools that are likely to be around for while?  For a P2Pool LTC mining pool operation, see http://pool.fabulouspanda.co.uk:9327/static/.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best pool it that has minimal ping response time to your mining PC. I have found mining pool lists for different coins with ping monitoring: https://investoon.com/mining_pools/